# What if the input of a simple function question is X?

Tags: functions

I know how to answer function questions when they are like:

fg(3)  when f(x) = x + 3 and g(x) = x^2

But what do I do when the question is like:

fg(x)  when f(x) = x + 3 and g(x) = x^2

[Or for a exam example click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq0CE.png)

Comment: Compose the two functions, instead of "3" use "$x$".

Comment: Clarification: By $fg(x)$ does your textbook mean the product $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ or does it mean the composition $f\left(g(x)\right)$?

Comment: Composition I believe

Answer (score 1):

For understanding the composition of two functions such as $f(x)=x+3$ and $g(x)=x^2$ it may be useful to first write the function is so-called **blank parenthesis form**.

\begin{equation}
f(\quad)=(\quad)+3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(\quad)=(\quad)^2
\end{equation}

Then use the form

\begin{equation}
fg(x)=f(g(x)) \text{ by definition of composition}
\end{equation} 
Then

\begin{equation} fg(x)=f(g(x))= (g(x))+3=x^2+3
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
gf(x)=g(f(x))=(f(x))^2=(x+3)^2=x^2+6x+9
\end{equation}

Comment: I should add that some textbooks define $fg(x)$ as the product of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ rather than the composition. Such textbooks write the composition as $f\circ g(x)$.

Comment: As an apparently new StackExchange user you should know that when you find a comment or answer to your question useful you are expected to upvote it. If you do not find it useful or if you think the responder has not understood your question you can make a comment including @username and the user will get a notice of your response.